# event that catches all: mouse click, touch, and stylus in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, events, touch

Is there an event in WPF that catches touch, mouse, and stylus events in one. StylusSystemGesture captures touch and stylus but not mouse. So I also have to bind MouseLeftButtonUp. If I bind both I have both calling my function so it gets called twice.

Touch and stylus do get promoted to mouse events but not when Manipulation is enabled. So I need an event that catches all three when manipultation is enabled.